# ¿Como logro actualizar entradas , salidas de productos mediante Trigger?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

1. Tengo una base de datos llamado bodega con 4 tablas que son productos, detallesentrada, detallessalida y inventario.
2. Tengo creado los `Triggers` para actualizar después de que en la tabla detalles tanto como de entrada y salida se ingresen los valores correspondientes.
3. En la tabla de inventario quiero que se reflejen ya los valores en automático en sus columnas(entradas, salidas y stock).
4. Una  vez ya ingresado el dato del producto, así como también los detalles cuando entran o salen y realizo la consulta uniendo la tabla de productos con la detalles se muestran correctamente, pero donde tengo el problema es cuando hago la consulta de uniendo la tabla productos con la de inventario no me muestra ningún valor ya calculado las sumas y restas, o hay otra manera sin usar `Trigger`.

**Scritps**

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
id_PRO int auto_increment primary key,
codigo_pro varchar(10) not null,
descripcion_pro varchar(20)not null
);

CREATE TABLE detallesEntrada(
id_DE int auto_increment primary key,
fechaEntrada date,
unidades int,
id_PRO int,
FOREIGN KEY (id_PRO) REFERENCES productos (id_PRO)
 );

CREATE TABLE detallesSalida(
id_DS int auto_increment primary key,
fechaSalida date,
unidades int,
id_PRO int,
FOREIGN KEY (id_PRO) REFERENCES productos (id_PRO)
);


CREATE TABLE inventario(
id_inventario int auto_increment primary key,
entradas int,
salidas int,
stock int,
id_PRO int,
FOREIGN KEY (id_PRO) REFERENCES productos (id_PRO)
);
```

**Triggers**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER InventarioEntrada after insert on detallesentrada for each row 
begin
UPDATE inventario
SET stock = stock + NEW.unidades,entradas = entradas + NEW.unidades
WHERE id_inventario = NEW.id_PRO;
end;
//
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER InventarioSalida after insert on detallessalida for each row 
begin
Update inventario
set stock = stock-NEW.unidades,salidas=salidas+NEW.unidades
where id_inventario = NEW.id_PRO;
end;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Productos insertados**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En detallesentrada de ingresaron 14 unidades**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En detallessalidas salieron 4 unidades**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizo la consulta uniendo la tabla productos para que me muestre el código de producto y la descripción, y en la tabla inventario me muestre en la columna entrada  las 14 unidades , en salida 4 y l stock muestre ya restado 10, pero me muestra sin ningún valor o el `Trigger`esta algo mal.

```
SELECT p.codigo_pro,p.descripcion_pro,i.entradas,i.salidas,i.stock FROM inventario as i INNER JOIN productos as p ON i.id_PRO = p.id_PRO;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo que estas preguntando....

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta la consulta que dices que trae datos incorrectos. Ojalá con algunos datos de prueba

Comment: @Alfabravo ya añadí la consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, ahora sí entiendo. Pasa que un UPDATE (como el del trigger) no crea registros nuevos. Si no has insertado un registro para el `id_inventario` correspondiente, el UPDATE dice OK, actualicé cero registros.

Podrías validar si existe el registro para ese id_inventario y, si no existe, crearlo.
Para las salidas, estaría raro que permitas salir algo que no ha tenido entradas, así que deberías arrojar un error.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER InventarioEntrada after insert on detallesentrada for each row 
begin
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inventario WHERE id_inventario = NEW.id_PRO) > 0 THEN
  UPDATE inventario
  SET stock = stock + NEW.unidades, entradas = entradas + NEW.unidades
  WHERE id_inventario = NEW.id_PRO;
ELSE
  INSERT INTO inventario(id_inventario, stock, salidas) 
   VALUES(NEW.id_PRO, NEW.unidades, 0);
END IF
end;
//
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER InventarioSalida after insert on detallessalida for each row 
begin
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inventario WHERE id_inventario = NEW.id_PRO) > 0 THEN
 Update inventario
 set stock = stock - NEW.unidades, salidas = salidas + NEW.unidades
 where id_inventario = NEW.id_PRO;
ELSE
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '¹No hay entradas del producto!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
END IF
end;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: me servio tu apoyo solo agregue en el insert into el valor de entradas ya que en esa columna me mostraba null y hago la consulta del inventario y todo marcha bien, solo hay un pequeño detalle al hacer otra consulta de ambas tablas como la de productos y inventario no me muestra los valores, lo realizo tal como se  detalle en mi ultima pregunta.

Comment: Alfabravo ya lo resolví  y esta funcionando las consultas así como los valores  muchas gracias por compartir tu inteligencia.